# java array month table

Tags: java, arrays

I tried this coding, but it didn't show the output that I want. It suppose to start with 1 = 31

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class cth   {
public static void main(String args[])       {


  int day[]= new int[12];

     day[0] = 31;
     day[1] = 28;
     day[2] = 31;
     day[3] = 30;
     day[4] = 31;
     day[5] = 30;
     day[6] = 31;
     day[7] = 31;
     day[8] = 30;
     day[9] = 31;
     day[10] = 30;
     day[11] = 31;

              System.out.printf("\t  Year 2013\n\n");
              System.out.printf("\t--------------\n\n");
              System.out.printf("\t%s%8s\n\n","Month","cou.day");

              for (int j = 1; j<=day.length; j++){

              System.out.printf("\t%2d%8d\n", j, day[j]);
              }
  }
  }
```

What is the function of %2d8d% ? i was confused

Comment: Those are special formatting converters. [This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) explains how they work.

Comment: You should probably change `day[j]` to `day[j-1]` since the indexes in your array start at 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int j = 1; j<=day.length; j++){
    System.out.printf("\t%2d%8d\n", j, day[j]);
}
```

Your first line of output would have been `1 28`, but your array starts from `[0]`, so either loop from `0` or print `day[j-1]`.

For the meaning of `%2d8d%`, this is print one integer padded with enough spaces to fill up 2 columns, then a second integer with padding to 8 characters. See [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) for more details.